# How can I catch this error? (POST Content-Length ...)

Tags: php

While uploading image I'm getting this error: (max 8mb an image)

```
Warning: POST Content-Length of 14259306 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0
```

How can I display this message customly? I mean I want to put that error in CSS style. thank you....

Answer (score 13):

Maybe you wanna try something like this.

```
if (isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_LENGTH"])) {
    if ($_SERVER["CONTENT_LENGTH"] > ((int)ini_get('post_max_size') * 1024 * 1024)) {
        die('<script type="text/javascript">window.open("some page youre gonna handle the error","_self");</script>');
    }
}
```

Comment: I have also decided to use this approach, just now. While the approach/check seems right, it's still incomplete. In this example, the warning is already printed and the user can see the warning. This warning also seems to break the POST request. The `$_POST` is empty ... A better solution would be to store a custom error/warning message (in session?) and redirect to the same page and then show the custom message (that's what I'm doing), or simply redirect to another page and handle the problem there. No need to stay on the same* (warning printed) page.

Answer (score 10):

In case of common errors you need to set error handler. See [here](https://www.php.net/set-error-handler) for details. **BUT**

> If errors occur before the script is executed (e.g. on file uploads)
> the custom error handler cannot be called since it is not registered
> at that time.

Comment: This is an important notice that you cant catch the error in the PHP.

Answer (score 5):

```
if ($_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'] < 8380000) {
 ... your code
} else {
    ... Your Error Message
}
```

You can also increase the maximum size in the `php.ini`

```
post_max_size = 60M
upload_max_filesize = 60M
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13566992/970175) from @Batu-Zet to check in the code and then make sure `display_errors` is turned off in your `php.ini` file:

```
display_errors=Off
```

Answer (score 0):

You can limit max size of uploaded files in two ways:

1. Include `<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="..." />` in HTML form;
2. Set up `upload_max_filesize` in php.ini.

If you try to upload file bigger than `upload_max_filesize` PHP will raise warning like this before PHP script will run:

> Warning: POST Content-Length of 14259306 bytes exceeds the limit of
>   8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0

`$_FILES` and `$_POST['MAX_FILE_SIZE']` variables will be empty in this case. It seams that `UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE` never works. Anyway, I never caught it in my code.

When uploaded file is smaller than `upload_max_filesize` than some elements of `$_FILES` array may contain `UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE` error code for files bigger than `MAX_FILE_SIZE`.

You can catch both situation by next PHP script:

```
<?php

$warning = error_get_last();
if ($warning !== null && stripos($warning['message'], 'POST Content-Length of') !== false) {
  error_clear_last();
  echo 'Upload is bigger than '.ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
}
else if ($_FILES['input_name']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE) {
  echo 'Upload is bigger than '.$_POST['MAX_FILE_SIZE'];
}
```

Answer (score -5):

Wrap the upload in a TRY / CATCH. Catch the error and handle within the CATCH.

```
try {
    :: file upload ::
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Comment: It doesnt throw an exception it generatesa php warning. This would only work if he uses `set_error_handler` to use a custom function which throws exceptions when PHP errors are generated.