# Kohana app showing PHP warning messages

Tags: php, kohana

I'm building an app with the Kohana framework. Image uploading is part of this. When I try to upload a file that exceeds the max post file size (20M) I get a PHP warning message instead of my Validation messages or Kohana's error handler.

> Warning: POST Content-Length of 26871468 bytes exceeds the limit of 20971520 bytes in Unknown on line 0

Here is my Validation code:

```
$validate = Validation::factory($files);
$validate
    ->rule('photo', 'Upload::not_empty', array($files['photo']))
    ->rule('photo', 'Upload::valid')
    ->rule('photo', 'Upload::size', array($files['photo'], '10M'))
    ->rule('photo', 'Upload::type', array($files['photo'], array('jpg', 'png', 'gif')));

if ($validate->check())
{
    Upload::save($files['photo'], 'test.jpg', 'uploads');
}
```

This warning is thrown at a much higher level than anything I can access from my MVC. How can I intercept this error? (Obviously when the app is online PHP warnings won't be shown to the user, but during development I need the warnings.)

Comment: Try `if ($_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'] < 20971520) { //display error }`

Comment: @AmalMurali I think you meant > right? :) I tried that and it works, but the PHP warning is still being shown.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315461/how-can-i-catch-this-error-post-content-length

Answer (score 1):

Before the file can be validated, he must be loaded to the server. And because the file is to big for that, you receive an error from the server.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. It sounds like to handle this warning I'd have to edit Kohana's core code, correct?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure at all , just trying something , Might wanna separate them:

```
$validate
->rule('photo', 'Upload::not_empty', array($files['photo']);
$validate->rule('photo', 'Upload::valid');
$validate->rule('photo', 'Upload::size', array($files['photo'], '10M');
$validate->rule('photo', 'Upload::type', array($files['photo'], array('jpg', 'png', 'gif');
```

Because it seems like it just ignores all the validations, Might be because of this , again , im not sure.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. The PHP warning is being thrown before it even gets to the Controller.